# How to refresh the screen in OpenGL after something is printed?

Tags: android, opengl, glut

I have a couple of if-statements and if one of them is true it will print a character on the screen.

```
char d = 'a';
char c = 'b';

if(A == TRUE) //see comments below
{
Print(200,200,d);
}

if(B == TRUE)
{
Print(200,200,c);
}

void Print(int x, int y, char u)
{
glRasterPos2f(x,y);
glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, u);
}
```

The problem is that if A is true, it will print 'a' on the screen correctly, but if afterwards B is true and A not anymore it will print 'b' on the screen while the character 'a' is still there. How can I solve this so that only one character is on the screen. Any help would be appreciated.

Big thanks to datenwolf. The most important thing is to put the glutPostRedisplay in the right place. I placed it at the end of my void Print(..) function. I just looked where I should place it and for me this works now (it was just a small adjustment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL's design is built on the premise, that the while window is redrawn if anything needs a change. Normally all drawing operations should be done from only a central display function. Changes that need to be reflected in what's visible on the screen should be dealt with by preparing the list of things to be drawn and then issue a full redraw event.

#### Update

*Actually you have a completely different problem*

In the statement `if(A = TRUE)` two things are happening:

- `A` gets assigned the value `TRUE`
- the result of that assignment (which is TRUE) is tested for truth, which it is and hence will always pass.

The same goes for `if(B = TRUE)`.

The right operator to use is `==` (two equal signs in a row). With most compilers you can enable a warning and turn that into an error, that assignments are not allowed in a branching statement. A stylistic approach is to write tests for equality as

```
if( TRUE == A )
```

which avoids accidents like yours. However in your case you can simply write

```
if( A )
```

without any comparison operators at all. And I strongly suggest you do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to get it to work. I use the displaymode GLUT_DOUBLE. I have a line that is drawn in the display function. Using glutPostRedisplay() the screen should be redrawn if for example a key is pressed but that isn't the case. It still puts two characters on top of each other.

Comment: @user3468100: Oh, I just saw the true problem of yours. It's an easy mistake to do, that can be avoided using "Yoda Condiationals". See my answer update to come.

Comment: Thank you again. That is 100% true :p . But what if for example I want to click on a certain space in the screen (x coordinate between 400 and 500 and y coordinate between 600 and 700) and then press a key and show that on the screen. If you could help me with that I would be really thankful !

Comment: Well, in the mouse input handler test if the click coordinates fall into the chosen range (`if( 400 <= click.x && 500 >= click.x && 600 <= click.y && 700 >= click.y ){ clicked_into_target = TRUE } else { clicked_into_target = FALSE; } glutPostRedisplay();`), and then in the display function draw dependent on the value of `clicked_into_target`. You should of course not hardcode the target rect coordinate range as numbers into the code, but use named variables / constants.

Comment: I have edited the code above. Now my problem is clear I hope.